# Recursive function not working

Tags: php, function, recursion

This is functions not working is correct:

```
function primaryParent($id)
{
    $result = $this->querySingle('select parentid from menu where id = ' . $id . ' limit 1');
    if ($result) 
        $result = $this->primaryParent($result);
    else 
        return $result;
}
```

What is my error?

This function must return primary parent id, not first parent.

In database items group by parrentid field, and then show:

- Primary menu item

  - Submenu item 1
  - Submenu item 2

    - Sub submenu item 1
    - Sub submenu item 2
    - Sub submenu item 3
  - Submenu item 3

I need get primary menu item id from sub submenu item.

I use SQLite3 functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not returning anything for the `if ($result)` case.
You probably want `return $this->primaryParent($result);`.

Comment: Sure, but if I use ```return $this->primaryParent($result);``` in ```if ($result)``` case I see this error: ```AH00052: child pid 23153 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)``` and Nginx show ```502 Bad Gateway```

Comment: That's pretty damn uncommon and has apparently uncovered some bug in the underlying PHP code.